# How to create dtable in R using data?

Tags: r

For an assignment I am supposed to insert data from a study in R. I need to pick two binary variables and perform a simulation to obtain a p-value. Data from n=239 college students. I have to pick two binary varibales to perform the simulation on, so I chose gender and left-hand/right-hand. But, I am having trouble inserting data into a dtable.

```
dtable = matrix(c(3,10,12,5), byrow=TRUE, ncol=2, dimnames = 
     list(c("Improvement","No Improvement"), 
          c("Control","Dolphins")))
```

I am supposed to use the above format to create a dtable, but I am not sure what to put in the matrix(c), as there are 200 repsonses to the study for my binary variables (1,2 represents both female/male and left/right handed response). Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I have tried to figure this out for hours. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful for you

```
dtable <-data.frame(response= rep(c("Improvement","No Improvement"),100),control=sample(1:200,200),Dolphins = sample(1:200,200,replace=T))
```